# Active Directory - Define logon hours from Group Policy (Windows 2003 R2)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a bunch of computers in an OU in my Active Directory.
These computers are located on a theoretically less secure site (they are in a warehouse)
I want to stop these computers being logged in to (by anyone) between certain hours... Can I do this in Group Policy?

I've seen "Logon Hours" in the account tab in AD but this isn't quite what I want... I wan't to stop the computers from logging in using ANY account between certain times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't functionality built-in to Windows to do what you're looking for.

The idea below is a cheap hack and could easily be subverted, but it might get you what you want w/o using third-party software.

If I were going to do what you're trying to do, I'd build a [security template](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738340(WS.10).aspx) that adds "Users" to the "Deny logon locally" user right assignment, and a second one that removes it (i.e. sets it back to the stock "Guest" only). Once those are built and tested (be careful testing it-- it'll stop even "Administrator" from being able to logon locally) I'd write a script to [apply the security templates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742512.aspx#EBAA) using a scheduled task. At the appropriate time, apply the template to prevent interactive logons, and then apply the template to restore the ability to logon interactively.